# How to eliminate a tuple according to the column value

Tags: python, django

When a user register a law, the user id (`user_id`) and the law id (`law_id`) is saved in `marked` table.

When a user insert a description in a law, a new tuple is created with the same `user_id` and the same `law_id`.

I'm trying to get the law data only once, but my query is returning a law for each tuple that exists in `marked` table.

My model:

```
class Law(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)    
    descriptionlaw = models.TextField('Descrição', blank = True, null=True)

class Marked(models.Model):
    law = models.ForeignKey(Law, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Lei', related_name='marcacaoArtigos')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='markedUser', related_name='markedUser')
    description = models.TextField('Descrição', blank = True, null=True)
```

My query:

```
user1 = User.objects.get(id= request.user.id)    
marked = user1.markedUser.all()
```

That's my table:

```
"id"    "description"   "law_id"  "user_id"
"1"       "desc1"         "1"       "1"
"2"       "desc2"         "1"       "1"
"3"       "desc3"         "1"       "1" 
"4"       "desc4"         "2"       "1" 
"5"       "desc5"         "2"       "1"
```

So in this case, I want to receive `law_id=1` once and `law_id=2` once. But I'm receiving `law_id=1` three times and `law_id=2` twice.

**----------edit-----------**

In my view I need to show the value of the `law 1` and the `law 2`.
example of the values to show on my view:

```
{{law.id}} = 1,
{{law.name}} = law1,
{{law.descriptionlaw}} -> 'law1 description'

{{law.id}} = 2,
{{law.name}} = law2,
{{law.descriptionlaw}} -> 'law2 description'
```

Comment: it worked but I got another problem: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'details' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['leis\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']`. I think that is because I use this url in details page:  `<a href="{% url 'laws:details'  pk=marked.law.id %}">`. Any idea how to solve it. Tks for you answear.

Comment: I got the problem but I don't know how to solve. The problem is that I need to return all the `marked` table fields but its returning only `lei_id`

Comment: I edited. I really hope be clear.

Comment: I'm gonna read it right now. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my view I need to show the value of the law 1 and the law 2

You want to show law properties, then you should to select `law` models:

```
user1 = User.objects.get(id= request.user.id)    
laws = Law.objects.filter( marcacaoArtigos__user = user1 ).distinct()
```

Because you have a `related_name` on `Marked` to `Law`, you shoud to use it on query to compose the `filter` expression.

Remember to send `laws` to template.